# My boss resigned, who do I report to?

Tags: professionalism, resignation

So I work in a typical office setting for the highest ranking non-c-suite officer of the company. Yesterday, my boss brought me in and informed me that due to management decisions regarding another employee (some drama), she is resigning and had put in her notice.

Now I report directly to her, and although her boss is technically the CFO, she handles things both for the CEO and COO as well, to the point where she in charge of departments under them as well. Our CFO doesn't have too much knowledge of what I do and hasn't controlled any of the projects that I've taken on other than those he asked be assigned to me himself. When my boss is no longer here, all of the C-suite will have an equal claim to being my direct supervisor (as I do some critical reporting that each would like to utilize for their own personal requests).

Note: My boss has been cut out of the process due to an administrative review (part of the whole drama thing), so she does not have any knowledge of a transition. There is nobody filling the role, just people taking bits and pieces of the position.

**How can I tell who I will be under to start a smoother transition, or alternatively, how (and who) can I approach to find out?**

Comment: Is your boss still there? If so, can't you ask her before she leaves? She'd still technically be your superior until she leaves, unless you've been told otherwise.

Comment: @Kozaky She is, that's a good idea. Mind putting it in an answer with a small section in case she goes on gardening leave before I get a chance to meet?

Comment: @DavidK What's obvious to you is not obvious to everyone, myself included. Although this maybe should have been addressed in the meeting I had, it's well within the topics of the help center. There's not a rule stating that questions need to be some unsolvable mystery. I've edited it to add some background, but it's hardly a company specific problem.

Comment: It sounds like, if people are taking bits and pieces of the position, you should be part of that process and decide what you're going to take or who has taken the right part for you to report to them. If you sit back and wait, there may not be anything left for you.

Comment: I don't do any of the items my boss does regularly. Put simply, she's the controller, and I'm the financial analyst. I create ad hoc reports for her to use in meetings and create financial reports to provide them, but they're already provided to all of the C-suite. I've never done things for JUST my boss, and have ALWAYS done things for just about everyone at the company.

Answer (score 5):

You should ideally have been told this yesterday by your boss during her talk to you (or you should have asked then).

Ask your boss if she's still there - maybe she's still negotiating the handover process and allocating resources/reorganizing teams etc.

Ask if you can help in any way, it seems more productive than just sitting there waiting.